# Forms with composite entry box renders wrong value

Tags: javascript, forms, coffeescript, reactjs

I have the following setup:
`FormPage` renders a list of items and an `EntryBox` at the bottom.
`EntryBox` is composed of an `<input type="number" />` and a `<select .../>`. Each component has its own handler in `EntryBox` and they update the composite state. On the callback from `setState()` I also call the `EntryBox`'s own `onChange` provided in the props.
`FormPage`'s handler gets called and it updates the form's state with the latest change.

I am seeing a disconnect between the number of times I click to increase/decrease the number in the `<input>` and the actual state rendered.

I suspect I am forcing data to flow in the wrong direction, but cannot pinpoint the best practice for doing this.

Edit: some coffeescript

```
@NumberField = React.createClass
  render: ->
        <input type="number" value={this.props.value} onChange={@onChange}/>

  onChange: (e) ->
        return unless @props.onValueChange?
        value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
        @props.onValueChange(value)


@ProductType = React.createClass
    displayName: 'ProductType'
    getInitialState: ->
        options: []
        selection: -1

    componentDidMount: ->
        # get options form AJAX call

    bubble_up: ->
        @props.onChange( @state.selection )

    componentWillMount: ->
        @setState( { selection: @props.product_id })

    componentWillReceiveProps: (nextProps) ->
        @setState( { selection: @props.product_id })

    render: ->
        options = []
        sorted = @state.options.sort( @_by_name )
        sorted.forEach (x) => 
          options.push( <option value={x.id} key={x.id}>{x.name}</option> )

        <select value={@state.selection} onChange={@onChange}>{options}</select>

    onChange:(event)->
        @setState({selection:event.target.value}, @bubble_up)


@EntryBox = React.createClass
    displayName: 'EntryBox'
    getInitialState: ->
        amount: 0
        product_id: -1
    handleAmountChange:(newAmount) -> 
        @props.onChange( {amount: newAmount, product_id: @state.product_id })
    handleProductChange:(new_product_id) -> 
        @props.onChange( {amount: @state.amount, product_id: new_product_id })
    componentWillMount: ->
        @setState( { amount: @props.amount, product_id: @props.product_id })

    componentWillReceiveProps: (nextProps) ->
        @setState( { amount: @props.amount, product_id: @props.product_id })
    render: ->
        <div className="entry">
            <NumberField onValueChange={@handleAmountChange} value={@state.amount} />
            <ProductType product_id={@state.product_id } onChange={@handleProductChange} />
        </div>


@FormPage= React.createClass
    displayName: 'FormPage'

    getInitialState: ->
        items: []
        entry:
            amount: 0
            product_id: -1

    render: ->
        nodes = @state.items.map ( entry, i ) =>
            <ReactBootstrap.Row key={i}>
                <FixedEntry entry={entry}  />
                <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="danger" bsSize="xsmall" onClick={@onDeleteEntry} data-idx={i}>delete</ReactBootstrap.Button>
            </ReactBootstrap.Row>

        <ReactBootstrap.Grid>
            {nodes}
            <ReactBootstrap.Row>
                <form onSubmit={@_handle_submit}>
                    <EntryBox onChange={@onEntryChange}  amount={@state.entry.amount} product_id={@state.entry.product_id} />
                    <button>add</button>
                </form>
            </ReactBootstrap.Row>
        </ReactBootstrap.Grid>

    bubble_up: ->
        @props.onChange( @state.items )
    onEntryChange:(entry) ->
        @setState( {entry: entry} )

    onDeleteEntry:(event) ->
        $btn         = $(event.target)
        idx          = $btn.data("idx")
        currentItems = @state.items
        nextItems    = React.addons.update( currentItems, $splice: [[ idx, 1 ]] )
        @setState( {items: nextItems}, @bubble_up )

    _handle_submit: (event) ->
        event.preventDefault()
        if @state.entry.amount > 0 
            nextItems = @state.items.concat([ @state.entry ])
            nextEntry = 
                amount:0
                product_id: -1
            @setState({items: nextItems, entry: nextEntry }, @bubble_up )
```

Comment: Could you provide a little bit of the code? I'm not following the structure you've got currently.

Comment: It sounds a little suspect when you are forced to do a callback after a setState, not just inferring from the new state what to do. Could you paste some code? Which component is calling the setState, EntryBox or FormPage?